# Relativistic Energy of a body

Tags: special-relativity, potential-energy, mass-energy

When a body of mass $m$ moves with a velocity $v$, its relativistic mass increases as $\gamma m$.
Relativistic potential energy of the body equals $mc^2$ at all velocities. Then how the increase of mass does not make the potential energy increase? But instead, it makes the kinetic energy increase?

Comment: The energy $E=mc^2$ is nothing to do with potential energy. It is the [rest energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass#Rest_energy) of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You seem confuse how the rest mass $m_0$ (often written as simply $m$ in newer literature and simply called *the* mass) and the relativistic mass $m$ (often not used at all in newer literature) are connected to potential and kinetic energy.

The rest mass is the mass measured in an inertial frame in which the object is at rest, the relativistic mass is the mass observed in a moving frame (if we consider the mass to change instead of adapting the formula for the momentum as is common in newer treatments).

Then total (not potential) energy of a free particle is $E = \gamma m_0 c^2 = mc^2$ the potential energy depends on the external fields and does not at all come to play in problems involving free particles.

If we Taylor expand $\gamma$ for small $v$ in the formula for $E$ we retrieve the classical kinetic energy (plus a constant shift of $m_0c^2$, but if we consistently shift energy by a constant in classical mechanics all equations still hold). This energy shift $m_0c^2$ is called *rest energy*.

The use of the term kinetic energy is not entirely uniform in all fields and texts. In particle physics one often says that the kinetic energy is $T = (\gamma-1)m_0c^2$, that is the total energy of the free particle minus the rest energy.

Some texts also call $T = \gamma mc^2$ the kinetic energy, which then is non-zero for a particle at rest (which seems unnatural), but up to a factor of $1/c$ the 0-component in the momentum four-vector corresponding to the movement (and therefore seems natural).

Comment: The total energy (mass included) of a free particle (i.e. no potential energy) is $E = \gamma m_0 c^2$. The *kinetic energy* (exclusive of mass and potential) is $T = (\gamma - 1)m_0 c^2$. In the ultra-relativistic approximation ($\gamma \gg 1$) it is reasonable to conflate the two, but not in general.

Comment: I would say both definitions could be acceptable? I am quite certain I have seen books that define $\gamma m_0 c^2$ as the kinetic energy (since taking energies apart into contributions is to some degree artificial this boils down to a discussion of nomenclature.) I will try to find a book supporting my nomenclature and edit it if I don't find one. (I've definitely seen your definition before as well).

Comment: I would argue *strongly* against that. Kinetic energy is the energy of motion, and the mass energy exists without relative motion.

Comment: The relativistic kinetic energy equals [(gamma-1) mutiplied by mc^2. And the total energy equals mc^2. i.e we added the term mc^2 to the kinetic energy to get the total energy. Then what is the rerm mc^2. Isn't it the potential energy ?

Comment: @user193647 That is the mass energy, which is not a potential energy. It is a feature for which physics built on Galilean relativity has no analogue.

Comment: At least some German theoretical physics introduction books (e.g. H. Schulz: Physik mit Bleistift. 6th edition. Verlag Harri Deutsch, Frankfurt am Main, 2006) use the notation $T$ for $\gamma m_0 c^2$ and call this the kinetic energy. (Which underlines my point, that it is a matter of nomenclature that is not handled completely consistently by all authors). This definition has of course the slightly weird consequence, that the kinetic energy of a particle at rest is not zero.

Comment: @dmckee You say it is the mass energy. How the mass energy is constant and does not increase with mass increase ?

Comment: @user193647 Because the (invariant) mass does not increase (as it is measured in the rest frame).

Comment: @SebastianRiese That is ... bizarre. Particle physics types (like me) are quite clear that kinetic energy is what you have to add to your particles to make your beam. Definitely $(\gamma-1) m c^2$ (with the $_0$ dropped because we also only talk about invariant mass).

Comment: Yes, I will edit the answer to reflect the difference in nomenclature. And I included the ${}_0$ only for clarity. (Side note: In the introductory courses in particle physics we also referred to $(\gamma - 1)mc^2$ as the kinetic energy).

Answer (score 1):

Consider ditching the idea of relativistic mass, you don't need it. Modern literature often doesn't use it and it can lead to confusion. This question is a clear example of that.

Losing relativistic mass makes your question easy to answer. The **rest energy** is $E=mc^2$, by definition. So, no matter how fast your object is going, that will be its rest energy. The mass in this equation doesn't change.

Kinetic energy is $T=(\gamma -1)mc^2$ where $\gamma=\sqrt\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$. So if the speed goes from a smaller value to a larger value, the kinetic energy increases, but the rest energy stays the same.

This explains the change in kinetic energy with different speeds (and not different masses) and the sameness of the rest energy, all without the need for the idea of relativistic mass.